# do we have access to variables inside an INLINE function after its execution has ended,like what we don't have in normal user defined function?

Tags: c++, function, inline

calculation() function is not working when m making input() function outside the class...has it got something to do with inline function??

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class price
{
public:
int pen;
int rubber;
int scale;

void input()
{
    cout<<"enter the variables\n";
    cin>>pen>>rubber>>scale;
    cout<<"\n"<<pen<<" "<<rubber<<" "<<scale;
}
};

void calculate(price p)
{
    int rate[2],total;
    rate[0]=p.pen*5;
    rate[1]=p.rubber*3;
    rate[2]=p.scale*4;
    total=rate[0]+rate[1]+rate[2];
    cout<<"\n"<<total;
}

int main()
{
    price a,b,c;
    a.input();
    calculate(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int rate[2]` is an array of 2 elements, but you are trying to access 3 elements. That's Undefined Behaviour (and you don't need that array at all).

Comment: In addition to what Yksisarvinen says it's not obvious why you chose to use an array at all. What's wrong with the simpler code `total = p.pen*5 + p.rubber*3 + p.scale*4;`? There's no reason to add an array into this calculation

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "is not working"?

Comment: see my ques is ..in a user defined fn..all the memory alloc to it gets erased once the execution is done and this is what i expected my fn to do. But the calculate() is able to access the input() variables . It doesnt behave this way when i make input() outside the class because in that case ..calculate couldnt access the inside variables of input. I thought earlier it has something to do with property of instance member function that makes it an inline function..but m not sure.

Answer (score 5):

No we don't. `inline` has no effect at all on the semantics of a C++ function. It's only effect is on how that function is treated by the linker.

Comment: see my ques is ..in a user defined fn..all the memory alloc to it gets erased once the execution is done and this is what i expected my fn to do. But the calculate() is able to  access the input() variables . It doesnt behave this way when i make input() outside the class because in that case ..calculate couldnt access the inside variables of input. I thought earlier it has something to do with property of  instance member function that makes it an inline function..but m not sure.pls help

Comment: @AnveK I assume you are talknig about the `pen`, `rubber` and `scale` variables. Those are *class variables*. They are declared in the `price` class and so they don't get erased when the `input` function exits. Instead then only get erased when the `a` variable is erased, and since `a` is declared in `main` that only happens when you exit `main` and the program ends.

Comment: @AnveK The only variables that are erased when `input` exits are variables that are **declared** in `input`, but there are no variables declared in `input` in your code, so nothing gets erased.